# Artemis MQ how can sender get reception acknowledge

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

Hello is there a possibility that sender A puts a message with time to live of 30sec into a queue.
And get a:

- ACK notification if receiver B got/processed the msg
- NACK if ttl is reached before receiver B got the msgs

Is there any possibility for this without implement in the business logic?

The used programming language: java
The preferred protocol: jms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous.

If by "sender" you mean the actual `javax.jms.MessageProducer`, `javax.jms.QueueSender`, or `javax.jms.TopicPublisher` then the answer is no. In JMS (and in most other asynchronous messaging systems) the consumers and producers are logically de-coupled. In other words, producers don't know (and usually don't care) what consumers are doing. Therefore, there's no way for the JMS producer to automatically get an ACK notification if a consumer got/processed the message it sent or get a NACK if the message's TTL elapsed before being consumed.

However, if by "sender" you just mean the sending *application* then the answer is more hopeful. You can get expiration notifications via the [management notification](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management-notifications) address (which is similar to Tibco's `$sys.monitor` topic) once you have configured the [NotificationActiveMQServerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html#using-the-notificationactivemqserverplugin). The NotificationActiveMQServerPlugin doesn't support acknowledgement notifications, but you could easily extend the plugin to support them since there are already hooks in the plugin architecture to capture message acknowledgements.

Comment: Yes this generally fact i know. But for example tibco ems is also an jms broker and support some “magic” topics for N/ACK receiving.

Comment: The Tibco EMS Server provides topics like:   
// Install ACK listener        "$sys.monitor.Q.a.MY.QUEUE.I.SEND.MSG.TO"
// Install NACK Listener    "$sys.monitor.Q.p.MY.QUEUE.I.SEND.MSG.TO"